# SQL Limit min and max value in database

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_CD(
CDnr                int identity(1,1),
CDTitel             nvarchar(80) NOT NULL,
CDduur              int,
CDprijs             smallmoney,
```

So I am creating this table, is there any way I can limit the value of CDprijs to be between 0 and 100?

Comment: what is your RDBMS?, you may use a `CHECK CONSTRAINT`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a check constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_CD(
CDnr                int identity(1,1),
CDTitel             nvarchar(80) NOT NULL,
CDduur              int,
CDprijs             smallmoney,
check (CDprijs between 0 and 100),
```

Comment: great, will this work for MySQL? I am not sure but as far as I know in mysql the check constraint will be ignored

Comment: I don't know if it works for MySQL. (No dbms specified, so I gave an ANSI SQL answer - that will work with several dbms products.)

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks for answering my seemingly simple question that I just couldn't find the answer to!!

Comment: @Farhęg: no it will not work on MySQL - MySQL still has no check constraints (plus `identity` and `nvarchar` are also not valid for MySQL)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yes, I just noticed to check constraint and didn't see the identity and nvarchar.