# Max value limit for Laravel integer value DB record column

Tags: php, database, laravel, postgresql

How would I, if possible, create an integer column in my database with a max limit.

**Example:**

- Let's call the column `X`
- Let's say the max limit is "30"

- if X is set to 12, then that is a valid value.
- if X is set to 31, then that is an invalid value.

I would like to do this in the database layer and not in my application layer.

So what would I put in my database migration file?

Example migration file:

```php
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Comment: mind my typo in the title of this post.

Comment: I don't think that is possible to set max value to mysql column with laravel. The only thing that probably will help you is to create a trigger for that action

Comment: [SQL Limit min and max value in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512620/sql-limit-min-and-max-value-in-database), no clue if laravel supports check constraints. But you can create the table by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column value limitation can be done via [check constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/ddl-constraints.html)

Blueprint does not support it.

You need to run raw sql query

```php
public function up()
{
    // table creation
    DB::statement('
        ALTER TABLE users 
        ADD CONSTRAINT users_x_check CHECK (x > 0 AND x <= 30)
    ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Limit min and max value in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512620/sql-limit-min-and-max-value-in-database), no clue if laravel supports check constraints. But you can create the table by hand. - @DefinitelynotRafal